# Redirect page with Class Based View (CBV) Django 2.1 Python

Tags: django, python-3.x, redirect, django-class-based-views

I want to direct users to a specific page based on their role. I'd like to implement something like this in a class based view.

```
def home_redirect(request):
    user_role = Profile.objects.get(user = request.user).role
    if user_role in internal_users:
        return redirect(reverse_lazy('home'))
    else:
        return redirect(reverse_lazy('event_list'))
```

I am aware of RedirectView. But how can I grab the request in a CBV in order to get the user.role as in `request.user.role`? I know I can get the user.role in certain functions *within* a CBV by like so:

```
class HomeRedirectView(RedirectView):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HomeRedirectView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['current_user'] = Profile.objects.get(user = self.request.user)
        user_role = context['current_user'].role
        return context

    #Can't access user_role but if I could I would do something like this
    if user_role in internal_users:
        url = reverse_lazy('home')
    else:
        url = reverse_lazy('event_list')
```

How can I access user_role outside of get_context_data() in a CBV?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a [**`RedirectView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/base/#redirectview), you do not need to implement a `get_context_data` function, the URL is determined by the [**`get_redirect_url`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.RedirectView.get_redirect_url), so you can implement this as:

```
class HomeRedirectView(RedirectView):

    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user_role = Profile.objects.get(user=self.request.user).role
        if user_role in internal_users:
            return reverse('home')
        else:
            return reverse('event_list')
```

The [**`url`** attribute [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.RedirectView.url) is only set if the URL is static, but you thus can implement `get_redirect_url` in case the content is non-static.